# How to replace apostrophes with just brackets on certain lines starting with a specific string?

Tags: json, vim

Sorry if this has been answered before, but I looked pretty hard and couldn't find a simple enough answer (without Surround).
I want to replace all "ROUTE:" lines followed by one or more separated digits with a comma-separated list, as well changes it to brackets.

```
{
  "siteid": 17994,
  "ROUTES": "11 10 59 17 25 18",
  "ROUTEDIRS": "11:NB,10:NBNB,59:NB,17:EB,25:NB,18:NB",
}
```

to this:

```
{
 "siteid": 17994,
 "ROUTES": [11, 10, 59, 17, 25, 18],
 "ROUTEDIRS": "11:NB,10:NBNB,59:NB,17:EB,25:NB,18:NB"
```

}

I've tried all sorts of combos, but the selective line (there are actually 15 different key/values) for ROUTES I can tackle, however having a tough time with brackets.  My initial approach was to separate the two, new line after all ROUTES, which worked, but then I still ran into the bracket issue.  All other questions suggest plugins.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Doing exactly as you suggested:

```
:g/ROUTES/s/:\s*\zs/\r/|s/"/[/|s/"/]/|s/\s\+/, /|-j
```

Steps:

- Execute only on "ROUTES" lines via `:g/ROUTES/{cmd}`
- Separating key and value via `s/:\s*/\r/`
- Replacing quotes with brackets, `s/"/[/|`s/"/]/`
- Replacing spaces with commas, `s/\s\+/, /`
- Joining back up the new value line with the key via `-join`

Alternatively, you could use a sub-replace-expression:

```
:g/ROUTES/s/:\s\zs"\(.*\)"/\='['.join(split(submatch(1), '\s\+'), ', ').']'
```

For more help see:

```
:h :g
:h :s
:h /\zs
:h :j
:h :range
:h sub-replace-expression
:h split()
:h join()
:h submatch()
```